# React cannot read setState of undefined

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I am trying to update the state by making api call in componentDidMount phase .

I need to do is to display the name of users . Few names are set in initial state which are working fine . Then i need to append more users which is returned by hitting a get api .

Pseudo code:

```
export class UserDetails extends Component {
constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
        users: [
            {
              id: 1,
              name: "aditya"
            }
        ]
    };
}
componentDidMount() {
    this.jsonList();
}

jsonList() {
    axios('https://api.myjson.com/bins/1fwkrw').then(function(response) {
        this.setState((prevState) => {
            {users: users.push(response.data.userdata)};
        });
    })
}

render() {
    return (
        <div className="users">
            {this.state.users.map(user => {
              return (
                <div>
                  <div key={user.id}>{user.name}</div>
                </div>
              )
            })}
        </div>
    );
}
}
```

But here i am getting error "Unhandled Rejection (TypeError): Cannot read property 'setState' of undefined" . Any help where i am going wrong ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Either change jsonList to an arrow function:

```
jsonList = () => {
    axios('https://api.myjson.com/bins/1fwkrw').then(function(response) {
        this.setState((prevState) => {
            {users: users.push(response.data.userdata)};
        });
    })
}
```

Or bind the method inside the constructer :

```
constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
        users: [
            {
              id: 1,
              name: "aditya"
            }
        ]
    };
   this.jsonList = this.jsonList.bind(this);
}
```

The way you wrote it, jsonList is not binded correctly , therefore - you cannot use this.setState since `this` is undefined .

Answer (score 1):

You need to bind your `this` in the `axios promise` and also not *mutate the state* by using `concat` instead of `push`

```
axios('https://api.myjson.com/bins/1fwkrw').then((response) => {
        this.setState((prevState) => {
            return {users: prevState.users.concat(response.data.userdata)};
        });
    })
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to use **es6** arrow for auto binding of this to the synthetic handlers.

```
jsonList = () => {
axios('https://api.myjson.com/bins/1fwkrw').then(function(response) {
    this.setState((prevState) => {
        {users: users.push(response.data.userdata)};
    });
})
}
```

Your component will re-render because that's how react use **Virtual Dom** concept. It will see changes and update only that part of component. It doesn't mean that component will be completely mounted again in DOM.
I hope this helps